# Tuning `@babel/preset-typescript` for tsconfig's new option `"moduleResolution": "bundler"`

Tags: typescript, babeljs

As title. I tried `"moduleResolution": "bundler"` of tsconfig.json recently and I’m not sure whether I would need to tune the settings of `@babel/preset-typescript`.

From my understanding, tuning tsconfig.json would change the behaviour of a language server, e.g. tsserver, and IDE would possibly provide different type-checking/intellisense rules. So I assume that if I don’t sync my tsconfig.json with the behaviour of `@babel/preset-typescript` then my code will be compiled into something that might not follow the rules proposed by my tsconfig.

It would also be great if anyone could share how you integrate typescript into webpack with other toolings. I’m just trying Babel’s preset first.